# unwanted behaviour after javascript mousedown event

Tags: javascript

I have made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m1c04nkr/1/) and I am using Chrome.
I want to drag the red dashed/dotted line on the left to the right. A new flex column is added on mouseup OR when you exceed a part of the container, depending on the number of columns already added. For now I just try to add max 5 columns.
The first "drag" works as expected

- mouse down
- while holding mousedown drag to right
- column is added on mouseup or when exceeding some width

Now I want to repeat these steps and add another one. But now the behaviour is different:

- mouse down
- drag it to the right **but it gets stuck**
- I **have to** release the mouse button and move to the right and get out of the function

Here is some code, I've tried some stuff with bubble true or false on the eventlisteners but no luck. Should I use other events?

```
var container = document.querySelector('.js-flex-container'),
    containerRow = container.querySelector('.js-flex-row'),
    oldX = 0,
    oldY = 0,
    rect = container.getBoundingClientRect(),
    mouseupEvent = new MouseEvent('mouseup'),
    newDiv,
    colCount,
    captureMouseMove = function captureMouseMove(event){
        var directionX = 0,
            directionY = 0;

        if ((event.clientX - rect.left) > oldX) {
            // "right"
            newDiv.style.width = oldX + 'px';

            if (oldX >= Math.round(rect.right / colCount)) {
                container.dispatchEvent(mouseupEvent);
            }
        }

        oldX = (event.clientX - rect.left);
    };

container.querySelector('.js-flex-column').addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){
    var colWidth = event.clientX - rect.left,
        columns = container.querySelectorAll('.col');

    colCount = columns.length + 1;

    newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.className = 'col-x';
    columns[0].parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv, columns[0]);
    container.addEventListener('mousemove', captureMouseMove);
});

container.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    console.log('mouseup');

    if (typeof newDiv !== 'undefined') {
        newDiv.style.width = '';
        newDiv.className = 'col col-' + colCount;
        container.removeEventListener('mousemove', captureMouseMove);
    }
});
```

Comment: unclear what the problem is. do you want to be able to create unlimited columns within the area or border the columns or what is the issue? I ran the code and created 5 columns successfully by dragging the line from left to right

Comment: ...and which browser is everyone using?

Comment: @RachelGallen I've updated the question, I hope it's more clear

Comment: @LeeTaylor I am using Chrome

Comment: @RachelGallen that's all the code you need :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is doing something (funky) with the event after move.

Adding `event.preventDefault()` should do the trick

```js
    captureMouseMove = function captureMouseMove(event){
        var directionX = 0,
            directionY = 0;

        if ((event.clientX - rect.left) > oldX) {
            // "right"
            newDiv.style.width = oldX + 'px';

            if (oldX >= Math.round(rect.right / colCount)) {
                container.dispatchEvent(mouseupEvent);
            }
        }

        oldX = (event.clientX - rect.left);
        event.preventDefault(); // <---
    };
```

I would also recommend that you don't use `container` for `mouseup` events. Instead use `window` so releasing outside of the container doesn't cause issues. You could do the same for `mousemove`.